# How to configure Visual Studio Code to debug Django app in a virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I would like to have possibility to do a debugging of Django application in Visual Studio Code. I have a virtualenv, made a change in *launch.json* file that look like this:

```
{
    "name": "Django",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": true,
    "pythonPath": "${workspaceRoot}/.venv/bin/python2.7",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/mysite/manage.py",
    "args": [
        "runserver"
    ],
    "debugOptions": [
        "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
        "WaitOnNormalExit",
        "DjangoDebugging",
        "RedirectOutput"
    ]
},
```

put several break points in the code and run it. Unfortunately, the execution is not stopped on the line with break points. I tried the same without virtualenv and everything worked perfectly.

Please, point out what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For me, the following 2 changes worked

1. Add an absolute path for pythonPath
2. Use the `"--noreload"` option while starting the project

Here's the relevant part of my config

```
    {
        "name": "Django",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "/Users/xyz/Documents/dev/my_project/my_project_env/bin/python",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/manage.py",
        "args": [
            "runserver",
            "0.0.0.0:8080",
            "--noreload"                
        ],
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput",
            "DjangoDebugging"
        ]
    },
```

Comment: for window `pythonPath` will be (my env) `"pythonPath": "c:\\Python3",`

Comment: I have an issue running the Debug environment for Django application: my python is not in the virtual environment, while my django is.

Therefore, the solution I see everywhere with adding to the launch.json settings the line "pythonPath": "${workspaceRoot}/.venv/bin/python2.7", does not fit - I added more details [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68455529/not-able-to-activate-debug-in-vs-code-for-django-project-django-in-virtual-envi](here):

Answer (score 6):

1) Press CTRL + ,
2) Select Workspace Settings 
3) Add the following line in the settings file opened.

```
"python.pythonPath": "path_to_your_env"
```

You're done!

Comment: Good point to use the workspace settings, as you can use standard launch.json files

Comment: This helps, adding the `"python"` in `launch.json` -> `configurations` seems to not work

Answer (score 4):

This official tutorial worked in my case.

Just needed to open the "command palette" of VS Code and select my Python Interpreter to the virtual environment:

[image]

[image]

Full reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django#_create-a-project-environment-for-the-django-tutorial