# Not able to activate debug in VS-code for Django project (Django in virtual environment)

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have an issue running the Debug environment for Django application in VS-code:

my python is not in the virtual environment,
while my django is.

Therefore, the solution I see everywhere with adding to the launch.json settings the line `"pythonPath": "${workspaceRoot}/.venv/bin/python2.7",`
does not fit, and I end up having the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? 
Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

When working on the application, I launch the setting environement using the following command:

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1
```

Can anyone help me out to declare my virtual environment the proper way in the launch.json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestion of https://stackoverflow.com/users/13877794/omid, I was able to find the solution:

I opened command palette, chose `Python: select Interpreter`, and then after selecting the workspace I was interested in, I typed in `.\venv\Scripts\python.exe` which works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you've created a virtual env lets say with `python -m venv my_env`, you should "select Interpreter" and define a path like this:

```
./my_env/bin/python
```

make sure you choose correct version (python2/3) and
usually there's no need to make launch.json manually.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ... that's was not working. But it put me on the right track: I opened command palette, chose 'Python: select Interpreter", and then after selecting the workspace I was interested in, I typed in ".\venv\Scripts\python.exe" which works fine for me. Thanks  !

Comment: oh, my bad you are on windows, that's right. well done